# ArrayList Serializable Android

Tags: android, serializable

I am trying to pass a `ArrayList<Polygon>` using `intent.putExtra()`.

I get **IOException** writing serializable object (name=Polygon.polygon).

Polygon is a class I made and have implements Serializable on this class.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main.class);
intent.putExtra("polygons", (ArrayList<Polygon>)this.polygons);

startActivity(intent);
```

The Polygon class has an `ArrayList<Point>` to hold a list of points for a polygon with a few getters and setters, that is all. I have implements Serializable on the Polygon class but I am getting that exception from the above code.

```
public class Polygon implements Serializable{

    ArrayList<Point> polygon;

    public Polygon(){ 
        polygon = new ArrayList();
    }

    public int getSize(){
        return polygon.size();
    }

    public ArrayList<Point> getPointArray(){
        return this.polygon;
    }

    public void addPoint(int x, int y, int mapWidth, int mapHeight, int canvasWidth, int canvasHeight){
        //going to scale up here
        float scaleX = mapWidth / canvasWidth;
        float scaleY = mapHeight / canvasHeight;

        polygon.add(new Point((int)(x*scaleX),(int)(y*scaleY)));
    }

    public void removePoint(int index){
        polygon.remove(index);
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Without posting the implementation(code), you probably won't get much useful help.

Comment: HI I have added some of the code.

Comment: Well, when I said that, I meant the code from the `Polygon` class that handles the serialization. **But**, since you posted that, what is `this.polygons`, and why do you need to cast it to `ArrayList<Polygon>`? I assumed it would already be that type.

Comment: I don't need to cast i was just trying that out to see if it made a difference which it doesn't :) this.polygons is defined ArrayList<Polygon> polygons. What do you mean about handle the serialization, I thought implementing Serializable would be enough to send this field over? I have added the Polygon class above if that helps.

Comment: Take a look at the parcable interface. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html here you can find an explanation http://shri.blog.kraya.co.uk/2010/04/26/android-parcel-data-to-pass-between-activities-using-parcelable-classes/

Comment: Can you post the exception?

Answer (score 0):

If it is [android.graphics.Point](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Point.html) that you're using in your Polygon class then you should use [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) because Point implements Parcelable and not Serializable.

If using serialization you need to add the following permission to your Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```